# Pixel and percentage width divs side-by-side

Tags: css, width

I've found a lot of similar questions, and tried out several solutions (including some of the so-called "holy grail" CSS layouts), but they don't quite do what I need.

I have a containing div (a CSS containing block) with id `right`. Inside it on the left side, I want a fixed-width div (a splitter bar, but it doesn't matter what it's being used for; id `splitpane`); on the right, filling the rest of the space, another div (id `right-box` below).

I've tried making the two inner divs `display: inline-block` (with `vertical-align: top`), setting the left one to `width: 3px`, but then there's no way to set the right to have width 100% - 3px. I've also tried using the `float: left`/`margin-left: -100%`/`margin-left: 3px` trick, but it has the same problem: the 100% plus the 3px overflows the parent containing block and causes a scroll bar to pop up. (Of course, it's not the scroll bar per se that's the problem; I could use `overflow: hidden` to remove it, but then content on the right would be truncated.)

Currently I'm using `width: 99.5%` for the right div, but that's a terrible hack (and is subject to overflow depending on screen width). It looks a bit like this:

```
<div id="right"><div id="splitpane"></div><div id="right-box">
  ...
</div></div>
```

With CSS as follows (float version, but the inline-block version is similar):

```
#right {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 100%;
  width: 85%;  /* this is part of a larger div */
}
#right-box {
  width: 99.5%; /* stupid hack; actually want 100% - 3px for splitter */
  height: 100%;
}
#splitpane {
  float: left;
  width: 3px;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
  border-left: solid gray 1px;
  border-right: solid gray 1px;
  cursor: e-resize;
}
```

Is it even possible to do this? This is for an internal app., so solutions only need to work in Firefox 3 (if they are specific to FF3, though, preferably it's because the solution is standards-compliant but other browsers aren't, not because it's using Firefox-only code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible. Because block level elements automatically expand to take up any remaining horizontal space, you can utilise a block level element next to an uncleared floated element with your desired width.

```
<style type="text/css">
    div {
        height: 100px;
    }
    #container {
        width: 100%;
    }
    #left {
        background: #FF0;
    }
    #splitpane {
        position: relative;
        float: right;
        background: #000;
        width: 3px;
    }
</style>

<div id="container">
    <div id="splitpane"></div>
    <div id="left"></div>
</div>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/georeith/W4YMD/1/

Answer (score 3):

DIVs are the wrong element type for this since they don't "talk" to each other. You can achieve this easily with a table:

```
<table style="width:200px">
<tr>
    <td id="splitpane" style="width: 3px">...</td>
    <td id="rightBox" style="width: 100%">...</td>
<tr>
</table>
```

The 100% will make the rightBox as wide as possible but within the limits of the table.

Comment: This solution appears to require that I specify an absolute width for the containing element (`width:200px` in the above example); I don't want to have to do that. Plus, I'd prefer not to use tables.

Comment: You only need to specify a width if you don't like the default of 100%. And tables are OK to use even with CSS. DIVs should be used for content that is *below* each other, not next to each other on the same line.

Comment: have you heard about CSS float?

Comment: @rochal: Have you heard about all the problems floats cause? Like creating N elements with the exact same height where N > 2?

Answer (score 2):

why you didn't use **margin-left** (since it was float layout) on right box?

so no need to create a splitter div...

```
#right{
width:200px; /*specify some width*/
}
#rightbox{
float:left;
margin-left: 3px; /*replace the splitter*/
/*margin: 0 3px; /*use this to give left & right splitter*/ */
}
```

yeah something like that, i hate empty div, it's not semantic and it's like putting a splitter on the "old" table way

Comment: Divs aren't semantic in the first place. You're supposed to use divs to mark up things that have no meaning, that's why it's called a "div" (arbitrary division).

Comment: yes i know div not semantic, what i mean was "empty element" was not semantic

Comment: I don't want to specify an absolute width for anything except the splitter.

Answer (score 0):

If the div #right-box is only going to contain non-floated content it might be an idea to just put the content inside #right instead and let it wrap around the floated #splitpane.