# Position div beside another one

Tags: html, css, position

I want to position a div beside another one. They both should have a width of 100%, whereby the left div has a width specified in px. This width can vary. I want the right div to expand to the right side, so that both divs together take 100%.

I've made a fiddle to describe my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/2gWLn/
As you can see the words "right" are not in one line. I've tried to solve that by applying a `padding-left` or `float: left` to the right div. But this does not work because the width of the left div can vary, so I can't specify that as `padding-left`.

How can I solve that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pixel and percentage width divs side-by-side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/641861/pixel-and-percentage-width-divs-side-by-side)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following may work:

```css
.right {
    width: auto;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: yellow;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Set `overflow: auto` to `.right` and this will establish a new block formatting context for `.right` and hence, prevent the content of `.right` from interacting with the adjacent floated element.  Also, set the width value to `auto` instead of `100%`. (A width value of `100%` works in Firefox, but not in Chrome or IE.)

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/9X6VY/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/H7zqT/ Seems not to work. The right div is now beneath the first container.

Comment: The solution works in Firefox but not in Chrome and not in IE, will see if a fix is possible...

Comment: @priojewo The cross-browser issue can be fixed by setting the `width` value to `auto` for `.right`, please see updated demo.